# Javascript : Extract part of a URL

Tags: javascript

In a URL that's originating from Facebook, the origination URLs look like this.

1. example.com/post.htm?fb_action_ids=
2. example.com/post/?fb_action_ids=
3. example.com/post?fb_action_ids=
4. example.com/post.php?id=1&fb_action_ids=

If the general URL form look like that using javascript how can we extract the part that's before **?fb_action_ids=** ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url.split('?')[0];
```

`url` being the variable that contains the `URL`